# Local variable not accessible from another method

Tags: c#, .net

In my code i have the following:

```
public void PopulateForm(int i)
{
    DAL.TicketsDataSetTableAdapters.TicketDetailsTableAdapter fobj = new DAL.TicketsDataSetTableAdapters.TicketDetailsTableAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = fobj.GetTicketUpdates(txtSupportRef.Text);
    txtShortDesc.Text = dt.Rows[0].Table.Rows[i]["ShortDesc"].ToString();
    txtNextStep.Text = dt.Rows[0].Table.Rows[i]["NextStep"].ToString();
    txtLastUpdated.Text = dt.Rows[0].Table.Rows[i]["LastUpdated"].ToString();
}
```

Then in another area of the code behind i have:

```
protected void btnNext_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = (int)ViewState["recordIndex"];
    i = i >= dt.Rows[0].Table.Rows.Count - 1 ? 0 : i + 1;
    PopulateForm(i);
}
```

But when i build the solution, it says:

**`The name 'dt' does not exist in the current context`**

Comment: I want to do some code reuse. I dont want to instantiate the datatable more than i have too.

Comment: This is really basic. You declare dt as a local variable on the PopulateForm method. Outside that method it doesn't exist

Comment: Yes, it may be basic... But i wasnt aware of public and private....

Comment: So i am I not allowed to ask?

Comment: It's not public vs private, dt is local to the function. You probably (maybe?) wand to declare it as a class variable and initialize in the class constructor. (Learn basics of object oriented programming.)

Comment: None of the books explained clearly what the difference was.... I believe in learning by example and trial and error...

Comment: I agree that this is basic, but we all need to learn and the OP seems just to need to learn. In a nutshell, you should declare `dt` in each method you use it in - unless the value of `dt` needs to be shared between methods and then it should be declared once at the class-level.

Comment: I know an Asian language very fluently. If someone asked me how to say a phrase which i thought was very basic. I would not tell them "this is very basic" as it come across like the person has a superior complex and very patronizing. Actually in this scenario, i would appreciate the person wants to learn and I would help them and explain the different ways to say a phrase. Surely in this community we must help one another, we just want to learn!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is related to the variable scope. When you declare a variable inside a method, it can only be accessible inside that method and it doesn't exist outside it.

If you want to reuse that variable content, you should move it to a higher level, as the class level:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

public void PopulateForm(int i)
{
    // ... 
}

protected void btnNext_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ... 
}
```

But, in this case, you should be aware the `dt` variable will be empty when you call the `btnNext_Click1`, as it will only be populated on `PopulateForm` call.

Comment: It should only be at the class-level if the state needs to be shared. If it's just being done to give a single declaration then it's potentially going to lead to buggy code.

Comment: @Enigmativity, you're right: "If you want to reuse that variable content, (...)"